# Is running PHP-FPM as a jailed linux a good idea?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I have a user `tony` who is jailed to his home directroy, from here there is a WordPress website being served. However, by default php-fpm is the user that is running the php-fpm daemon. This causes issues as php-fpm doesn't have the writes to tony's files, so WordPress can't self update.

If i change the user of a php-fpm daemon to tony, WordPress can self update.

Is there any implications of this? nginx is still ran as nginx, it's only php-fpm that i'm changing.

Comment: instead, you could add every www-user (like tony) to the same group as php-fpm and make the user-dirs group-writable. Thats what UNIX filesystem permissions were made for. But be sure to remove every "other" - permission, `2670` will do just fine, sometimes `2770`

Comment: possibly even `3671`, feel free to create a test directory with test files and go to town

Comment: tony is now part of php-fpm, and php-fpm is now the user that runs the php-fpm daemon. I've set the permissions on the files to 644 and the directories to 775, but WordPress moans.

Comment: ...actually directories at 777 seems to work now (previously they did not).